# How to find out if two cells in a dataframe belong to the same pre-specified factor-level

Tags: r

I really dont know how to title this question better, so please bear with me.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dist1 <- matrix(runif(16),4,4)
dist2 <- matrix(runif(16),4,4)
rownames(dist1) <- colnames(dist1) <- paste0("A",1:4)
rownames(dist2) <- colnames(dist2) <- paste0("A",1:4)

m1 <- melt(dist1)
m2 <- melt(dist2)

final <- full_join(m1,m2, by=c("Var1","Var2"))
ggplot(final, aes(value.x,value.y)) + geom_point()
```

To illustrate my problem, i have a matrix with ecological distances (m1) and one with genetic distances (m2) for a number of biological species. I have merged both matrices and want to plot both distances versus each other.
Here is the twist:
The biological species belong to certain groups, which are given in the dataframe `species`. I want to check if a x,y pair (as in `final$Var1`, `final$Var2`) belongs to the same group of species (here "cat" or "dog"), and then want to color it specifically.
So, i need an R translation for:

```
species <- data.frame(spcs=as.character(paste0("A",1:4)),
                  grps=as.factor(c(rep("cat",2),(rep("dog",2)))))

final$group <- If (final$Var1,final$Var2) belongs to the same group as specified
  in species, then assign the species group here, else do nothing or assign NA
```

so i can proceed with

```
ggplot(final, aes(value.x,value.y, col=group)) + geom_point()
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that works.  I made some changes to the code you provided.  Full working example code given below.

```
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dist1 <- matrix(runif(16), 4, 4)
dist2 <- matrix(runif(16), 4, 4)
rownames(dist1) <- colnames(dist1) <- paste0("A", 1:4)
rownames(dist2) <- colnames(dist2) <- paste0("A", 1:4)
m1 <- melt(dist1)
m2 <- melt(dist2)
# I changed the by= argument here
final <- full_join(m1, m2, by=c("X1", "X2"))

# I made some changes to keep spcs character and grps factor
species <- data.frame(spcs=paste0("A", 1:4), 
  grps=as.factor(c(rep("cat", 2), (rep("dog", 2)))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# define new variables for final indicating group membership
final$g1 <- species$grps[match(final$X1, species$spcs)]
final$g2 <- species$grps[match(final$X2, species$spcs)]
final$group <- as.factor(with(final, ifelse(g1==g2, as.character(g1), "dif")))

# plot just the rows with matching groups
ggplot(final[final$group!="dif", ], aes(value.x, value.y, col=group)) + 
  geom_point()
# plot all the rows
ggplot(final, aes(value.x, value.y, col=group)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set up the `species` data frame with two columns that correspond to `X1` and `X2` in `final`, then merge based on those two columns:

```
species <- data.frame(X1=paste0("A",1:4),
                      X2=paste0("A",1:4),
                      grps=as.factor(c(rep("cat",2),(rep("dog",2)))))

final = merge(final, species, by=c("X1","X2"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Now you can plot the data using `grps` as the colour aesthetic:

```
ggplot(final, aes(value.x,value.y, colour=grps)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is true for - at least for me - for all cases when X1=X2. But this does not cover the cases A1 and A2, which are both cats as well (or A3 and A4, both being dogs).

Comment: So, in the example, the pairs A1-A1, A1-A2, A2-A1, A2-A2 should be identified as "both cats", hence should get the factor "cat".

Comment: For some reason, my colnames changed to Var1 and Var2, i edited the OP accordingly.

Comment: Then you just need to set up the `species` data frame so that it includes rows for each of those cases. For example, there should be a row `A1 A2 cats`, and similarly for each case you want to merge into your `final` data frame.

Comment: Ah, my species contain 748 pairwise comparisons in 25 groups, though :/. But thanks anyway!

Comment: If you have or can find any file that includes both the species names and the "X1" and "X2" values (or whatever they're called in your real data), even if various combinations are repeated multiple times, you can boil it down to a lookup table. Alternatively, it might not be that difficult to generate the lookup table if you can boil down the logic to a few rules that can be looped or vectorized.